# Minesweeper analyze goes to N-Queensland

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, combinatorics

As [@rolfl recently solved the N-Queens problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75517/n-queens-brute-force-bit-by-bit), I figured that it was time also for me to solve it.

My approach is significantly different from @rolfl's. I quickly realized that the N-Queens problem is just another [Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). Earlier, I have written a whole bunch of code for [solving Minesweeper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/analyzing-minesweeper-probabilities), so I figured that I could re-use that code and extend on it to solve N-Queens.

My code is *significantly* slower than @rolfl's (size 11 takes 3.5 seconds for me, while it takes 9 ms for @rolfl), which I am not very surprised about. My approach feels much more data-oriented and is a lot more flexible. (Who would have thought you could solve N-Queens by analyzing Minesweeper?)

The biggest changes I have done to my previous Minesweeper code are:

- Splitted `RootAnalyzeImpl` to `AnalyzeFactory` and `AnalyzeResult`
- Added `BoundedFieldRule` class, which the previously existing `FieldRule`
- Added `RuleConstraint` interface (implemented by `BoundedFieldRule`), to support potentially further extensions
- Moved the splitting of `FieldGroup`s to `AnalyzeFactory`
- Some modifications to `GameAnalyze` to support the new `RuleConstraint` interface, nothing major and is therefore not included in this post

I have had the `BoundedFieldRule` concept in mind for a while, and it can also be used in analyzing good old [minesweeper](/questions/tagged/minesweeper).

#### Class Summary (576 lines in 6 files, making a total of 15819 bytes)

- RuleConstraint.java: Interface for constraints to apply on the analyze
- BoundedFieldRule.java: A rule with both min and max value, for example `0 <= (a + b) <= 1`
- FieldRule.java: A rule where min and max value is the same, so for example `(a + b) = 1`
- AnalyzeFactory.java: Class responsible for adding rules and initiating the solving
- NQueens.java: Contains a method to create an `AnalyzeFactory` for the N-Queens problem
- IntegerPoints.java: Utility methods for `NQueens`

## Dependencies

- Java 6
- My [Minesweeper analyze code](https://github.com/Zomis/Minesweeper-Analyze/tree/ceec668e272ec8d86999e34bdb80be73449fb8ff)

## Code

This code can also be found on github:

- [Combinatorics](https://github.com/Zomis/Combinatorics)
- [Minesweper Analyze](https://github.com/Zomis/Minesweeper-Analyze/tree/ceec668e272ec8d86999e34bdb80be73449fb8ff)

**AnalyzeFactory.java:** (153 lines, 4400 bytes)

```
/**
 * Class for creating {@link AnalyzeResult}s
 * 
 * @author Simon Forsberg
 *
 * @param <T> The type of field to do analyze on
 */
public class AnalyzeFactory<T> {
    private final List<RuleConstraint<T>> rules = new ArrayList<RuleConstraint<T>>();

    AnalyzeFactory(Solution<T> known, List<RuleConstraint<T>> rules) {
        for (Entry<FieldGroup<T>, Integer> sol : known.getSetGroupValues().entrySet()) {
            this.rules.add(new FieldRule<T>(null, sol.getKey(), sol.getValue()));
        }
        this.rules.addAll(rules);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new, empty analyze factory
     */
    public AnalyzeFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Solve this analyze
     * 
     * @return An {@link AnalyzeResult} object for the result of the analyze.
     */
    public AnalyzeResult<T> solve() {
        List<RuleConstraint<T>> original = new ArrayList<RuleConstraint<T>>(this.rules.size());
        for (RuleConstraint<T> rule : this.rules) {
            original.add(rule.copy());
        }

        List<RuleConstraint<T>> inProgress = new ArrayList<RuleConstraint<T>>(this.rules.size());
        for (RuleConstraint<T> rule : this.rules) {
            inProgress.add(rule.copy());
        }

        final List<Solution<T>> solutions = new ArrayList<Solution<T>>();

        this.splitFieldRules(inProgress);

        double total = new GameAnalyze<T>(null, inProgress, null).solve(solutions);

        for (Solution<T> solution : solutions) {
            solution.setTotal(total);
        }

        List<FieldGroup<T>> groups = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>();
        if (!solutions.isEmpty()) {
            for (FieldGroup<T> group : solutions.get(0).getSetGroupValues().keySet()) {
                // All solutions should contain the same fieldgroups.
                groups.add(group);
            }
        }
        AnalyzeResultsImpl<T> result = new AnalyzeResultsImpl<T>(original, inProgress, groups, solutions, total);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Separate fields into field groups. Example <code>a + b + c = 2</code> and <code>b + c + d = 1</code> becomes <code>(a) + (b + c) = 2</code> and <code>(b + c) + (d) = 1</code>. This method is called automatically when calling {@link #solve()}
     * @param rules List of rules to split
     */
    public void splitFieldRules(List<RuleConstraint<T>> rules) {
        if (rules.size() <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        boolean splitPerformed = true;
        while (splitPerformed) {
            splitPerformed = false;
            for (RuleConstraint<T> a : rules) {
                for (RuleConstraint<T> b : rules) {
                    splitPerformed |= checkIntersection(a, b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIntersection(RuleConstraint<T> ruleA, RuleConstraint<T> ruleB) {
        if (ruleA == ruleB) {
            return false;
        }

        List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldsA = ruleA.fieldGroups();
        List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldsB = ruleB.fieldGroups();
        List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldsCopy = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(ruleA.fieldGroups());
        List<FieldGroup<T>> ruleFieldsCopy = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(ruleB.fieldGroups());

        for (FieldGroup<T> groupA : fieldsCopy) {
            for (FieldGroup<T> groupB : ruleFieldsCopy) {
                if (groupA == groupB) {
                    continue;
                }

                FieldGroupSplit<T> splitResult = FieldGroupSplit.split(groupA, groupB);
                if (splitResult == null) {
                    continue; // nothing to split
                }

                FieldGroup<T> both = splitResult.getBoth();
                FieldGroup<T> onlyA = splitResult.getOnlyA();
                FieldGroup<T> onlyB = splitResult.getOnlyB();

                fieldsA.remove(groupA);
                fieldsA.add(both);
                if (!onlyA.isEmpty()) { 
                    fieldsA.add(onlyA);
                }

                fieldsB.remove(groupB);
                fieldsB.add(both);
                if (!onlyB.isEmpty()) { 
                    fieldsB.add(onlyB);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Split the current field rules that has been added to this object
     */
    public void splitFieldRules() {
        this.splitFieldRules(rules);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new rule constraint that needs to be respected in all solutions
     * 
     * @param rule {@link FieldRule} to add
     */
    public void addRule(RuleConstraint<T> rule) {
        this.rules.add(rule);
    }

    /**
     * Get the rules that has been added to this analyze
     * 
     * @return List of {@link FieldRule}s that has been added
     */
    public List<RuleConstraint<T>> getRules() {
        return new ArrayList<RuleConstraint<T>>(this.rules);
    }
}
```

**BoundedFieldRule.java:** (188 lines, 4773 bytes)

```
/**
 * A constraint of a number of fields or {@link FieldGroup}s that should have a sum within a specific range
 * 
 * @author Simon Forsberg
 * @param <T> Field type
 */
public class BoundedFieldRule<T> implements RuleConstraint<T> {

    private final T cause;
    protected final List<FieldGroup<T>> fields;
    protected int maxResult = 0;
    protected int minResult = 0;

    /**
     * Create a copy of an existing rule.
     * 
     * @param copyFrom Rule to copy
     */
    private BoundedFieldRule(BoundedFieldRule<T> copyFrom) {
        this.cause = copyFrom.cause;
        this.fields = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(copyFrom.fields);
        this.minResult = copyFrom.minResult;
        this.maxResult = copyFrom.maxResult;
    }

    /**
     * Create a rule from a list of fields and a result (create a new FieldGroup for it)
     * 
     * @param cause The reason for why this rule is added (optional, may be null)
     * @param rule Fields that this rule applies to
     * @param result The value that should be forced for the fields
     */
    public BoundedFieldRule(T cause, Collection<T> rule, int min, int max) {
        this.cause = cause;
        this.fields = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>();
        this.fields.add(new FieldGroup<T>(rule));
        this.minResult = min;
        this.maxResult = max;
    }

    public BoundedFieldRule(T cause, List<FieldGroup<T>> fields, int min, int max) {
        this.cause = cause;
        this.fields = new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(fields);
        this.minResult = min;
        this.maxResult = max;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return fields.isEmpty() && minResult <= 0 && maxResult >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public SimplifyResult simplify(GroupValues<T> knownValues) {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return SimplifyResult.NO_EFFECT;
        }

        Iterator<FieldGroup<T>> it = fields.iterator();
        // a + b <= 1 ---- a = 1 ---> b <= 0 ---> b = 0
        int totalCount = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            FieldGroup<T> group = it.next();
            Integer known = knownValues.get(group);
            if (known != null) {
                it.remove();
                minResult -= known;
                maxResult -= known;
            }
            else totalCount += group.size();
        }

        // a + b < 0 is not a valid rule
        if (maxResult < 0) {
            return SimplifyResult.FAILED_NEGATIVE_RESULT;
        }

        // a + b > 2 is not a valid rule.
        if (minResult > totalCount) {
            return SimplifyResult.FAILED_TOO_BIG_RESULT;
        }

        // (a + b) = 1 or (a + b) = 0 would give a value to the (a + b) group and simplify things.
        if (fields.size() == 1 && minResult == maxResult) {
            knownValues.put(fields.get(0), minResult);
            return clearRule();
        }

        // (a + b) + (c + d) <= 0 would give the value 0 to all field groups and simplify things
        if (maxResult == 0) {
            for (FieldGroup<T> field : fields) {
                knownValues.put(field, 0);
            }
            return clearRule();
        }

        // (a + b) + (c + d) = 4 would give the value {Group.SIZE} to all Groups.
        if (totalCount == minResult) {
            for (FieldGroup<T> field : fields) {
                knownValues.put(field, minResult * field.size() / totalCount);
            }
            return clearRule();
        }

        if (minResult <= 0 && maxResult >= totalCount) {
            // Rule is effectively useless
            clearRule();
        }

        return SimplifyResult.NO_EFFECT;
    }

    private SimplifyResult clearRule() {
        SimplifyResult simplifyResult = fields.isEmpty() ? SimplifyResult.NO_EFFECT : SimplifyResult.SIMPLIFIED;
        fields.clear();
        minResult = 0;
        maxResult = 0;
        return simplifyResult;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder rule = new StringBuilder();
        rule.append(minResult);
        rule.append(" <= ");
        boolean fieldAdded = false;
        for (FieldGroup<T> field : this.fields) {
            if (fieldAdded) {
                rule.append(" + ");
            }
            fieldAdded = true;
            rule.append(field.toString());
        }
        rule.append(" <= ");
        rule.append(maxResult);
        return rule.toString(); 
    }

    @Override
    public BoundedFieldRule<T> copy() {
        return new BoundedFieldRule<T>(this);
    }

    @Override
    public List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldGroups() {
        return this.fields;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldGroup<T> getSmallestFieldGroup() {
        if (this.fields.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        FieldGroup<T> result = this.fields.get(0);
        for (FieldGroup<T> group : this.fields) {
            int size = group.size();
            if (size == 1) {
                return group;
            }
            if (size < result.size()) {
                result = group;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public T getCause() {
        return cause;
    }

    public int getMinResult() {
        return minResult;
    }

    public int getMaxResult() {
        return maxResult;
    }

}
```

**FieldRule.java:** (86 lines, 2164 bytes)

```
/**
 * A constraint of a number of fields or {@link FieldGroup}s that should have a specific sum
 * 
 * @author Simon Forsberg
 * @param <T> Field type
 */
public class FieldRule<T> extends BoundedFieldRule<T> {

    /**
     * Create a copy of an existing rule.
     * 
     * @param copyFrom Rule to copy
     */
    private FieldRule(FieldRule<T> copyFrom) {
        super(copyFrom.getCause(), copyFrom.fields, copyFrom.getResult(), copyFrom.getResult());
    }

    /**
     * Create a rule from a list of fields and a result (create a new FieldGroup for it)
     * 
     * @param cause The reason for why this rule is added (optional, may be null)
     * @param rule Fields that this rule applies to
     * @param result The value that should be forced for the fields
     */
    public FieldRule(T cause, Collection<T> rule, int result) {
        super(cause, rule, result, result);
    }

    FieldRule(T cause, FieldGroup<T> group, int result) {
        super(cause, new ArrayList<T>(), result, result);
        this.fields.add(group);
    }

    public Collection<FieldGroup<T>> getFieldGroups() {
        return new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(this.fields);
    }

    public int getFieldsCountInGroups() {
        int fieldsCounter = 0;
        for (FieldGroup<T> group : fields) {
            fieldsCounter += group.size();
        }
        return fieldsCounter;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return this.getMinResult();
    }

    public double nCr() {
        if (this.fields.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Rule has more than one group.");
        }
        return Combinatorics.nCr(this.getFieldsCountInGroups(), this.minResult);
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxResult() {
        return getMinResult();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder rule = new StringBuilder();
        for (FieldGroup<T> field : this.fields) {
            if (rule.length() > 0) {
                rule.append(" + ");
            }
            rule.append(field.toString());
        }
        rule.append(" = ");
        rule.append(getResult());
        return rule.toString(); 
    }

    @Override
    public FieldRule<T> copy() {
        return new FieldRule<T>(this);
    }

}
```

**IntegerPoints.java:** (60 lines, 1592 bytes)

```
public class IntegerPoints {

    public static FieldRule<Integer> positionValue(int x, int y, int i, int size) {
        return new FieldRule<Integer>(pos(x, y, size), Arrays.asList(pos(x, y, size)), i);
    }

    public static List<Integer> createLine(int x, int y, int size, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        List<Integer> fields = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (x < size && y < size && x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
            fields.add(pos(x, y, size));
            y += offsetY;
            x += offsetX;
        }
        return fields;
    }

    public static String map(GroupValues<Integer> values, int size) {
        char[][] fields = new char[size][size];
        for (Entry<FieldGroup<Integer>, Integer> group : values.entrySet()) {
            Integer pos = group.getKey().get(0);
            Integer value = group.getValue();
            char ch = ' ';
            if (value == 1) {
                ch = '1';
            }
            else if (value == 0) {
                ch = '0';
            }
            fields[pos % size][pos / size] = ch;
        }

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                if (fields[x][y] == 0) {
                    str.append(' ');
                }
                else str.append(fields[x][y]);
            }
            str.append("\n");
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    public static Integer pos(int x, int y, int size) {
        return y * size + x;
    }

}
```

**NQueens.java:** (44 lines, 1575 bytes)

```
public class NQueens {
    public static AnalyzeFactory<Integer> createQueens(int size) {
        AnalyzeFactory<Integer> analyze = new AnalyzeFactory<Integer>();

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            // Diagonal from top to bottom-right
            analyze.addRule(new BoundedFieldRule<Integer>(0, IntegerPoints.createLine(x, 0, size, 1, 1), 0, 1));
            if (x != 0) {
                // Diagonals from left to bottom-right
                analyze.addRule(new BoundedFieldRule<Integer>(0, IntegerPoints.createLine(0, x, size, 1, 1), 0, 1));
            }

            // Diagonals from top to left-bottom
            analyze.addRule(new BoundedFieldRule<Integer>(0, IntegerPoints.createLine(x, 0, size, -1, 1), 0, 1));
            if (x != 0) {
                // Diagonals from right to left-bottom
                analyze.addRule(new BoundedFieldRule<Integer>(0, IntegerPoints.createLine(size - 1, x, size, -1, 1), 0, 1));
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            List<Integer> columnFields = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> rowFields = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                columnFields.add(IntegerPoints.pos(x, y, size));
                rowFields.add(IntegerPoints.pos(y, x, size));
            }
            analyze.addRule(new FieldRule<Integer>(0, columnFields, 1));
            analyze.addRule(new FieldRule<Integer>(0, rowFields, 1));
        }

        return analyze;
    }

}
```

**RuleConstraint.java:** (45 lines, 1315 bytes)

```
public interface RuleConstraint<T> {
    /**
     * Apply various values to this rule to potentially simplify it and learn something new
     * 
     * @param knownValues Known values that can be removed and cleaned up from this rule to simplify it
     * @return A {@link SimplifyResult} corresponding to how successful the simplification was
     */
    SimplifyResult simplify(GroupValues<T> knownValues);

    /**
     * Create a copy of this rule, for trial-and-error purposes
     * 
     * @return A copy of this rule in its current state
     */
    RuleConstraint<T> copy();

    /**
     * Determine whether or not this rule is finished and thus can be removed from the list of rules
     * 
     * @return True if this rule is successfully finished, false otherwise
     */
    boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * Find the best field group to branch on
     * 
     * @return The best {@link FieldGroup} to branch on, or null if this rule does not have a preference about how to branch
     */
    FieldGroup<T> getSmallestFieldGroup();

    /**
     * @return An indication on what caused this rule to be created
     */
    T getCause();

    /**
     * @return Direct access to the {@link FieldGroup}s in this rule, in order to split them
     */
    List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldGroups(); 
}
```

## Usage / Test

JUnit test is available on github:

- https://github.com/Zomis/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/test/java/net/zomis/combinatorics/NQueensTest.java

## Questions

- It feels a bit icky to have the `fieldGroups` method in the interface and directly return the internal list. I have been a lot back-and-forth about this. Is there a better way to organize the splitting of field groups?
- Is the inheritance between `FieldRule` and `BoundedFieldRule` done in a good way?
- Is it somehow possible to use some of @rolfl's ideas to make my approach faster and have both the flexibility of my approach and the performance of rolfl's?
- Any other comments appreciated

Answer (score 4):

**AnalyzeFactory**

The `checkIntersection()` method is doing more than the name implies. By reading this methodname one (at least me) would assume that neither `rulaA` nor `ruleB` would be changed. The direct (also through a method) access of the `BoundedFieldRule<T>`'s `fields` property smells for me.

Instead of letting these `fields` be accessed from outside, you should add methods to `RuleConstraint<T>` for adding to and removing from this `List<T>`.

**FieldRule**

> ```
> public double nCr() {
>     if (this.fields.size() != 1) {
>         throw new IllegalStateException("Rule has more than one group.");
>     }
>     return Combinatorics.nCr(this.getFieldsCountInGroups(), this.minResult);
> }
> ```

here the message of the `IllegalStateException` is misleading, because the condition is `! = 1`. So for the case that there are no `fields` this exception will be thrown also with the same message.

**RuleConstraint**

```
/**
 * Determine whether or not this rule is finished and thus can be removed from the list of rules
 * 
 * @return True if this rule is successfully finished, false otherwise
 */
boolean isEmpty();
```

Here the name of the method `isEmpty()` has nothing to do with the documentation which says "Determine whether or not this rule is finished". So better change this to e.g `isFinished()`.

**General**

The interface `RuleConstraint<T>` has

> ```
> List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldGroups();
> ```

and you add to `FieldRule<T>` another

> ```
> public Collection<FieldGroup<T>> getFieldGroups() {
>     return new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(this.fields);
> }
> ```

method. Also they aren't returning the same thing in the same way it is leading to misunderstandings.

**Refactoring**

```
public interface RuleConstraint<T> {  

    SimplifyResult simplify(GroupValues<T> knownValues);
    RuleConstraint<T> copy();  
    boolean isFinished();  // <- changed from isEmpty()  
    FieldGroup<T> getSmallestFieldGroup();  
    T getCause();  
    List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldGroups(); // still here, but should return a copy of the list
    void addFieldGroup(FieldGroup<T> fieldGroup);  // <- new
    void removeFieldGroup(FieldGroup<T> fieldGroup);  // <- new
    boolean intersects(RuleConstraint<T> rule);  // <- new
}
```

and the implementation of the `intersects()` method

```
@Override
public boolean intersects(RuleConstraint<T> rule) {

    if (rule == this) {
        return true;
    }

    for (FieldGroup<T> fieldGroup : fields) {
        for (FieldGroup<T> ruleFieldGroup: rule.fieldGroups()) {
            if (fieldGroup == ruleFieldGroup || !Collections.disjoint(fieldGroup, ruleFieldGroup)) {
                return true;
            }
    }

    return false;
}
```

leads inside `AnalyzeFactory` (after renaming the former `checkIntersection()` to `performSplit())` to

```
public void splitFieldRules(List<RuleConstraint<T>> rules) {
    if (rules.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    boolean hasIntersections = true;
    while (hasIntersections) {
        hasIntersections= false;
        for (RuleConstraint<T> a : rules) {
            for (RuleConstraint<T> b : rules) {
                if (a.intersects(b)) {
                    hasIntersections = true;
                    performSplit(a, b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Because `performSplit()` is only executed if `ruleA.intersects(ruleB)` we can make it void. We also remove the unneccessary check of `if (groupA == groupB)` because this is done in `FieldGroupSplit.split()` method also.

```
private void performSplit(RuleConstraint<T> ruleA, RuleConstraint<T> ruleB) {

    for (FieldGroup<T> groupA : ruleA.fieldGroups()) {
        for (FieldGroup<T> groupB : ruleB.fieldGroups()) {

            FieldGroupSplit<T> splitResult = FieldGroupSplit.split(groupA, groupB);
            if (splitResult == null) {
                continue; // nothing to split
            }

            FieldGroup<T> both = splitResult.getBoth();
            FieldGroup<T> onlyA = splitResult.getOnlyA();
            FieldGroup<T> onlyB = splitResult.getOnlyB();

            ruleA.removeFieldGroup(groupA);
            ruleA.addFieldGroup(both);
            if (!onlyA.isEmpty()) { 
                ruleA.addFieldGroup(onlyA);
            }

            ruleB.removeFieldGroup(groupB);
            ruleB.addFieldGroup(both);
            if (!onlyB.isEmpty()) { 
                ruleB.addFieldGroup(onlyB);
            }
            return;
        }
    }  

}
```

In `BoundedFieldRule<T>` class

```
@Override
public List<FieldGroup<T>> fieldGroups() {
    return  new ArrayList<FieldGroup<T>>(this.fields);
}
```