# NQueens Puzzle in Java

Tags: java, beginner, chess

Place N amount of queens in such a way that none of them can attack each other.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NQueensRewrite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter amount of queens");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] board = new int[n];
        fillBoard(board);
        printBoard(board);
    }

    public static void fillBoard(int[] board) {
        int queens = 1;
        while (queens < board.length) {
            boolean validColumnFound = false;
            //Start from previous confirmed column or check all if valid column found in row
            for (int column = board[queens] + 1; column < board.length; column++) {
                if (isValid(column, queens, board)) {
                    board[queens] = column;
                    queens++;
                    validColumnFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //If no other valid column is found, then clear the row and go back to try another column
            if (!validColumnFound) {
                board[queens] = 0;
                queens--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int column, int row, int[] board) {
        //Check if any other row has the specified column
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            if (board[i] == column) {
                return false;
            }

            //Check the differences bewteen the spaces if they are uniform (even)
            //If the difference between the column of ith row and column being checked is
            //the same as the difference between the current row and row being checked,
            //then some previous queen is diagnal to the current spot being checked
            if (Math.abs(board[i] - column) == Math.abs(i - row)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void printBoard(int[] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (board[i] == j) {
                    System.out.print("|Q");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("| ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've given answers to N-Queens questions before. [A Java one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75517/n-queens-brute-force-bit-by-bit/75564#75564) and [a C++ one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77669/chess-puzzle-improvement/77833#77833). I don't know how well they would apply to your code, but they might be worth reading. There are surely other good answers on the site, too.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92412/9357)

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to figure out your code. I have solved this problem a couple of times before, but found your code hard to read. In large part, because your variable names are misleading....

- `board` is not a board, it is an array of int, with the value of the queen's column. I see the board as being a 2D matrix, you have it as a 1D array.
- `queens` is not the number of queens, but the number of rows you have currently populated.

Then, your code is not as general-purpose as I was expecting.... Your code only ever finds solutions where the position (0,0) is a queen. Now, that's not to say that solutions with a queen there are wrong, but, are you sure? What if there is no solution with a queen in the corner....

If you know for sure there will be one, then you should at least document that..... if not, then it's a bug.

All in all, your code could use some more help to get it readable.

Comment: Ah I think I understand... What are some good resources or guidelines I could use to begin to write more readable code?