# Display all solutions for NQueens

Tags: java, chess, backtracking

In my previous NQueens Code Review question, [I received feedback](/a/90458/9357) saying that I should write a program that would find *all* solutions. This revised program should be more general than before.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RedoNQueens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of queens: ");
        int nQueens = input.nextInt();
        //Create board and clear it
        int[] board = new int[nQueens];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = -1;
        }

        //Place the first piece to get started
        int row = 0;
        board[row] = 0;
        row++;
        int column = 0;
        long solutions = 0;
        while (row >= 0) {
            if (isValid(row, column, board)) {
                board[row] = column;
                row++;
                column = 0;

                //Board completed?
                if (row >= board.length) {
                    solutions++;
                    System.out.println("Solution " + solutions);
                    printBoard(board);
                    row--;
                    column = board[row] + 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                //If current column is not valid
                column++;
                if (column >= board.length) {
                    board[row] = -1;
                    row--;
                    if (row >= 0)
                        column = board[row] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of solutions for " + nQueens + " queens is " + solutions);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int row, int column, int[] board) {
        if (column >= board.length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            //Check if column appears in any other row
            if (board[i] == column)
                return false;

            //Check both diagnals
            if (Math.abs(row - i) == Math.abs(column - board[i])) 
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (board[i] == j)
                    System.out.print("|Q");
                else
                    System.out.print("| ");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're looking for specifically in trying to revise your program past this point. So, here's a handful of general things I would change:

- Remove static modifier from your code. This can be done by creating an `NQueens` class, that maybe takes the N as a parameter to it's constructor, then can be run by calling a "run" method.
- Use curly braces on all your conditional statements. You're less likely to break code down the road that way.
- See all those comments you have? Instead of commenting on little sections of that, you could increase your code's readability by making those their own methods.

  Example: In the following code, maybe make a method that explains what you're doing here, such as `resetPosition` or something.

  ```
      //If current column is not valid
      column++;
      if (column >= board.length) {
          board[row] = -1;
          row--;
          if (row >= 0)
              column = board[row] + 1;
      }
  ```
- I would suggest trying to better name your iterators as well. `i` and `j` are just fine, but if you're actually iterating through something that has a name, such as row, column, etc. go ahead and use that. Again, easier to read and follow the algorithm.
- Similarly, row, column aren't totally obvious in how they're used. Would they be better represented as `currentRow` or `currentColumn`? Since you're using these as nodes to find new solutions from, it might makes sense to have a more descriptive name.
- `isValid`; what exactly is valid? Is that a valid representation of the board, a valid solution, or only part of the solution?
- Lastly, why isn't the board represented as a 2D array? You received this as feedback last time as well, but I second it. A game board is represented in 2-dimensional space, x and y. The same way a cube would be in 3-dimensional space and therefor hopefully be represented as a 3-dimensional array. Trying to represent objects outside their native dimension takes some time to understand. I would avoid this at all costs unless there are serious performance gains to be made.

I think the point I'm getting at here is that: Ideally, I shouldn't have to know anything about what the NQueens problem is in order to follow your code without much issue.